# Woocommerce prefix for phone number

Tags: woocommerce, phone-number, prefix

In my country we have 3 phone carriers. I would like to make these 3 a dropdown select at my woocommerce checkout for the phone number. So my customers have less of a chance to input it wrong.

Can someone help me if this is even possible?